# Bootstrap JS Tab and CSS : get rid of the underline style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap JS tab. Unfortunately, I deleted a few lines in my CSS file (and of course don't remember which one). Do you know how I could get rid of the underline style in my various tabs in order to restore a style similar to http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h ?

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: Thank a lot for your quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [text-decoration](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp).

```
.nav-tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Just for the tracability : may I suggest 'text-decoration' instead of decotation ... Then I will gladly accept your answer

Comment: I submitted an edit to make this more specific to bootstrap and to fix the typo. It'll eventually (hopefully) get accepted.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed :)